# jQuery - Selecting all NON-Matches?

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<div class="commentList>
  <div name="version-1>stuff</div>
  <div name="version-1>stuff</div>
  <div name="version-1>stuff</div>
  <div name="version-2>stuff</div>
  <div name="version-3>stuff</div>
  <div name="version-3>stuff</div>
</div>
```

I'd like a line of jquery that, given a version #, like 3, will update the.CommentList to only show div's with name="version-3" the others will be hidden?

Possible w/o IDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a `class` here since `name` isn't a valid attribute, then you can do this:

```
$(".commentList > div").hide();        //hide them all
$(".commentlist > .version-3").show(); //show what you want
```

If you *must* use name, the second line would look like this:

```
$(".commentlist > div[name='version-3']").show();
```

But..try and be valid with a class here.

Comment: Class, as Nick suggests, is the best approach

Comment: The problem with using class is thatI have other class items in class="" and i need to be able to get the version #, using $(this).class, and if it's got other stuff in the class, I can't get the version #?

Comment: Are there any other valid attributes for a DIV, other than ID and Class I could use?

Comment: @AnApprentice - In HTML5 `data-anything`, for example `data-version="3"`, you could use a class for a selector and the data attribute for quick fetching, in jQuery 1.4.3+ it's just `.data("version")` and it'll return `3` (as a number too, not a string).

Comment: Also, is there a way to build the selector dynamically, see this, which fails:  showCmtVersion = $(this).attr('id');
 $(".commentList > div").hide();        //hide them all
 $(".commentlist > ." showCmtVersion).show(); //show what you want

Comment: @AnApprentice - You're missing a `+` in there `$(".commentlist > ." + showCmtVersion).show();`

Answer (score 2):

would using the not selector be a bad idea?

```
$(".commentList").children().not("div[name='version-3']").hide();
```

although the idea of hiding them all first is not such a bad dea :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.commentList > div[name!=version-'+num+']').hide();`

but of course it wont toggle back any divs that may already be hidden. @Nick has a good answer.